# SpringBoot GetMapping Throwing always a 404 code

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a `springboot` application and I'm making a backend API email verification system. The post method works correctly as it should but I'm having problems with the `GetMapping` annotation and can't get the idea why is it returning me a `404 Status Code Error`.

Below I have the code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmailVerificationEndpoint {

    private final JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
    private final EmailProperties emailProperties;
    private final UserRepository userRepository; // Autowire the UserRepository

    @Autowired
    public EmailVerificationEndpoint(JavaMailSender javaMailSender, EmailProperties emailProperties, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
        this.emailProperties = emailProperties;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping("/send-verification-email")
    public ResponseEntity<String> sendVerificationEmail(@RequestBody EmailRequest emailRequest) {
        try {
            // This works fine
        } catch (MessagingException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // Handle exceptions (e.g., email sending failure) here
            // You can log an error message or return an error response to the frontend
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Error sending email");
        }
    }


    @GetMapping("/verify-email")
    public ResponseEntity<String> verifyEmail(@RequestParam String token) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Gets on GET");
            // Look up the user in your database by the provided token
            User user = userRepository.findByVerificationToken(token);

            if (user != null) {
                System.out.println("User found with verification token: " + token);
                // Mark the user as verified in your database
                user.setVerified(true);
                userRepository.save(user);

                // You can also return a success response or redirect to a confirmation page
                return ResponseEntity.ok("Email verified successfully");
            } else {
                // Token is not valid or user doesn't exist
                return ResponseEntity.notFound().build(); // Return a 404 status code
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exceptions here
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("An error occurred");
        }
    }


}
```

Can please someone help me with what's wrong about this? What I have been trying is not working...

Comment: How are you testing your endpoints?

Comment: The endpoint itself looks fine. The problem must then be in code that you haven't shown us, such as the client or an intermediate server or proxy.

Comment: Hey guys, @Alex_X1 and @Jorn thanks for your time guys but the problem was in the exactly on the  `sendVerificationEmail`. I fixed it and I'm closing this question now and thanks again for your time!!

Answer (score 1):

I think there could be problems in these different places:

- The `findByVerificationToken` method run the wrong query.
- he DB might not have the data you are searching for.
- You could be pointing to the wrong database (Test, Production, etc.).

By the way, I personally would write the code a little bit differently, keeping the code inside a try/catch block as minimal as possible.

```
@GetMapping("/verify-email")
    public ResponseEntity<String> verifyEmail(@RequestParam String token) {
        System.out.println("Gets on GET");
        User user;
        try {
            // Look up the user in your database by the provided token
            user = userRepository.findByVerificationToken(token);            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exceptions here
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("An error occurred");
        }
        if (user != null) {
            System.out.println("User found with verification token: " + token);
            // Mark the user as verified in your database
            user.setVerified(true);
            userRepository.save(user);

            // You can also return a success response or redirect to a confirmation page
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Email verified successfully");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No user found");
            // Token is not valid or user doesn't exist
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build(); // Return a 404 status code
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah while trying to find the culprit I thought to put the code in a `try and catch` just to make sure smth was escaping me. The other stuff were alright but the problem was on the `sendVerificationEmail` and `RequestMapping` I made a mess there which later I resolved. Thanks for your time Luke!